# Extracting URL in Vaadin

Tags: java, url, hyperlink, vaadin

I am currently using:

```
String url = Page.getCurrent().getLocation().toString();
```

to get the `url` in the address bar of the `vaadin app`. But the problem is that the app is redirected from `www.mywebsite.freehost.com` to `www.mywebsite.com` and the code that I am using is getting the `wrong url`. It is getting the `old url`.

---

> **I need the url from the redirect.**
>   *How can I do this? Does anyone know?*

Edit: I am hosting my Vaadin application on openshift and my html website on a different web host. I am redirecting the vaadin app to login.mywebsite.com. But instead of getting the URL login.mywebsite.com, I am getting the URL provided by openshift. How can I fix this?

Comment: Who is doing the redirect? Probably somehting outside vaadin

Comment: I use same code in two diffrent domains by same application for generating external links and everything works great.In my case I use reverse proxy but to be sure I also tested that code by typing ip address and returned location was typed ip. We need aditional information about what kind of redirect do you use, I think that cause your problems.

Comment: @AndréSchild Edited with more information

Comment: @daredesm I added how I host the app and how it is link to the website. Please take a look.

Comment: It's still not clear who is redirecting you...

Answer (score 1):

This code will give you the server name in the browser address bar.

```
  String url = ((VaadinServletRequest) VaadinService.getCurrentRequest()).getServerName();
```

Comment: This almost does what I want, but I am redirecting my app from openshift to login.mywebsite.com. The code that you provided is giving me the url for openshift, and not for login.mywebsite.com. Do you have a work around for this?

Comment: This worked for me. I changed returned variable name to "hostname" as it is just the name not a url :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = ((VaadinServletRequest)VaadinService.getCurrentRequest()).getHttpServletRequest();
```

(Request URL in String)

```
String requestUrl = httpServletRequest.getRequestURL().toString();
```